# Get users email from Fackbook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7, parse-platform, facebook-login

I have just made a new app and I have it all set up with Facebook login, and I have been approved for the email permission, but I seem to not to be getting the users email, I think I might be missing something in my code here is what I have:

```
// Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_likes", @"user_location", @"email", @"basic_info", @"user_activities", @"user_interests", @"user_birthday"];

// Login PFUser using facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {


    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error" message:@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error" message:[error description] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        user[@"school"] = @"";
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");

    }
    else  {

           NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        } 

    }
}];
```

If you could show of tell me what I am missing/ why I am not seeing my users email. I would really appreciate it. By the way I am using Parse.com as a backend.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logInWithPermissions:` method doesn't save the email attribute by default when it creates a new user. If you want to save the email of a Facebook user, after verifying that the user is already authenticated, you need to call `startForMeWithCompletionHandler:` method of [FBRequestConnection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequestConnection/#startForMeWithCompletionHandler) class. Your code should look like this in the last part:

```
NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"]
                                     forKey:@"email"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Great that works there, is there a way to get the email, if this is a new user, because when I put the code in the if(user.isNew) it does not work.